# Open source ABNF Parser implementation for Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I need an Augmented Backus-Naur Form Parser (RFC 5234) in Java to validate some languages.

In the interest of not re-inventing the wheel, I would prefer to use an existing open source implementation of ABNF Parser if one already exists.

I need open source because it allows me to maintain the code as needed.

Does anyone know of any that exists?

Comment: If the langauges you want to validate have ABNF specifications already, this is a good idea.   If they don't, you really should look for a parser generator system for which a number of langauge definitions have already been encoded and tested.  I'd be surprised to find a lot of existing language definitions in this particular formalism.

Comment: @IraBaxter RFC822 (email), RFC2045 (MIME), RFC3501 (IMAP)...  in fact every serious RFC I've worked with is in ABNF.

Comment: @djechlin: Interesting.  How many of the implementations use the ABNF directly?

Comment: @IraBaxter not sure what you mean? In some sense all of them since that's how the protocol is defined. What do you mean "how many"? How many ones that are on github and used in at least one obscure project that doesn't work? Do you mean how many are autogenerated from ABNF without human intervention? I don't know. Probably few since no one wants an HTML parser that throws errors on invalid HTML. Autogenerated as a first step then modified? Where's the line? In summary: no idea.

Comment: @IraBaxter to be less oblique, I was brought to this question since I'm looking for an IMAP parser generated from its ABNF. We use a big ugly regex which you're not supposed to do, and as such, parsing IMAP strings is the most expensive part of our entire application. I'm trying to fix that. Will look at the Javamail implementation among other things.

Comment: Why would using a regex make processing expensive?  I'd expect IMAP to be parser by an FSA or at worst a few nested FSAs, and regexes define (often implement) FSAs very efficiently (check out any lexer generator).  There's nothing about ABNF that would make you application efficient, if not implemented efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I have made the observation that [Parse2](http://www.parse2.com/) (see answer by Ralph) comes with some limitations:

- aparse doesn't like the comments and they have to be removed manually prior to code generation
- all statements need to end with a `;` at the end of the line
- aparse does not apply the "core" ABNF rules as defined RFC 5234 so they have to be copied from the RFC if your grammar is based on them
- aparse does not like loops in the grammar ( e.g. `S --> NT1 NT2 T1 ; NT1 --> S | T2 ; ...`) and might run into endless loops.

These observations have been confirmed by the developer of Parse2. So in short: Parse2 can parse a subset of ABNF grammars, however it will most likely have problems if you find an existing ABNF grammar and try to feed it to the software.

If you specify the ABNF grammars yourself and keep these limitations in mind, this library should work for you. If you have to work with existing ABNF grammars you might have to put additional effort into the grammar prior to code generation.

PS: the Parse2 library source code is currently not available even though the compiled binary (java byte code) is available freely.

Comment: further searched for ABNF parser generators and found [Java APG][1] (produces code that requires GPL v2+ libraries to run) and [abnf-parser-generator][2] (generated code is not licensed). So the best Java parser generator I could find is [abnf-parser-generator] as it generates a LR(1) [3]parser which are quite powerful.

   [1] http://www.coasttocoastresearch.com/
   [2] https://github.com/bqluan/abnf-parser-generator
   [3] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser

Answer (score 2):

[Parse2](http://www.parse2.com) generates source java for a parser from ABNF.